# querySelectorAll paused on exception in Chrome in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sizzle

My project is a Ruby on Rails project and it ran fine before, but recently it stopped working in Chrome. It runs fine in Safari and Firefox.

When I have the developer tools window open and I refresh the page it pauses several times during load to yell at me

`Paused on exception DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '\' is not a valid selector.`

then as I play through the breaks...

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '*,:x' is not a valid selector.`

`DOMException: Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': '[s!='']:x' is not a valid selector.`

The line of code is

`el.querySelectorAll("\\\f");`
`el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");`
`matches.call(el, "[s!='']:x");`

This issue happens in both sizzle.js and jquery.js respectively.

The Call stack is just dependencies and nothing I wrote.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TamRZ.png)

This problem started happening around a month or so ago when I updated Chrome, so I checked out a branch and reverted to a commit from multiple months ago. I then clobbered webpack and recompiled all my dependencies because I was positive I did not have this issue before. Alas, it does not work either.

Is there some bug in the most recent version of Chrome for MacOS?

Comment: The error messages seem pretty clear, you're using invalid selectors when you call `querySelectorAll()`. Please post a [mre] that shows how you're generating the selectors.

Comment: @Barmar By using jquery in my project. I specified that this happens in both sizzle.js and jquery.js. Sizzle was introduced as part of jQuery in version 1.3

Comment: You're still giving incorrect selectors. The first error says that you tried to use a backslash as a selector, that's not valid.

Comment: If there were such a serious bug in Chrome, you wouldn't be able to access many websites.

Comment: My bad, I had clicked some bad stuff in the Sources dev tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/main/src/sizzle.js#L879

This line of code in the jquery source code throws an exception.

Make sure the Sources dev tool for Chrome is not configured to `Pause on uncaught exceptions` and `Pause on caught exceptions`